# Name of book about teenage boy from the future

Tags: story-identification, books

The book is about a boy who is sent from the future by his parents to save to world. At first the boy doesn't know he is from the future until his fake parents are killed and he has to escape on a boat. Later he meets a talking dog and a girl who can shape shift. he keeps getting dream like messages from his future father warning him. He later has to face his uncle or something and find a crystal in the water that helps to regenerate the ocean and stuff

Comment: I always like the all inclusive "and stuff" descriptor.

Answer (score 6):

*[Firestorm](http://www.librarything.com/work/986357/reviews)* by David Klass.

> His mother is not his mother. His father is not his father. And if Jack hadn’t broken the high school rushing record that night, nothing would have changed. He’d just be going out for pizza, playing football, trying yet again to score with his girlfriend, P.J.
>
> But he did break the record. He appeared on the news. And now they have found him.
>
> Ripped from the only world he has ever known, Jack plunges into a space-time–bending game of survival with no way out.
>
> After centuries of abuse, the earth is dying, and it's up to Jack to reverse the decline before the Turning Point, when nothing will ever be the same again. Beaten into shape by a ninja babe and a huge telepathic man's best friend, Jack hurtles across the ocean to save the future from the present and to solve the mystery of his purpose.