# Book about kid from another planet being hidden on earth

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to figure out the title to a book I read and never got to finish a couple of years ago. It's about a kid from another planet who's been hidden on earth as a normal boy by his "protectors" until he breaks a football record at his highschool and is then found by what I would call bounty hunters. The whole plot of the story is him running from these bounty hunters while being taught that he's not like a normal person and that he has increased strength, speed, stamina, etc. Because he's from another planet with more advanced technology and more evolved people.

Comment: So you read it in the 2010s?

Comment: Can you remember anything else? For example, was it set in the USA (where "football" would mean American football), or somewhere else (where "football" would mean soccer).

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48849/name-of-book-about-teenage-boy-from-the-future

Answer (score 4):

**Firestorm** by David Klass (I'm not sure if we mark this as a duplicate question?)

[Name of book about teenage boy from the future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48849/name-of-book-about-teenage-boy-from-the-future)

> His mother is not his mother. His father is not his father. **But if Jack hadn't broken the high school rushing record** that night, he never would have known and nothing would have changed. He'd just be going out for pizza, playing football, trying yet again to score with his girlfriend, P.J. But he did break the record. He appeared on the news. And now they've found him.
>
> Seventeen-year-old Jack Danielson's life has always been normal– except that his parents have encouraged him to blend in and not try too hard. But then he learns that he is different, that **he has special powers and abilities**, and that he is from the future and has been sent back to save the planet. Strangers kill his adoptive parents and come after him, and the teens' only hope to survive is to trust in Gisco, a huge dog who speaks to him telepathically, and Eko, a ninja babe whose loyalties are ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible you're thinking of Pittacus Lore's *[I Am Number Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Number_Four)*?

> Most of the book is told in the first-person by Number Four, who takes the name John Smith. As the story begins, he and his guardian or Cepân, Henri, learns of the death of Number Three and move to Paradise, Ohio, assuming new identities. There, John befriends conspiracy theorist Sam Goode and "adopts" a dog identified by its name tag as "Bernie Kosar". He also meets and is attracted to a fellow student, Sarah Hart, who is working as a photographer. Sarah's ex-boyfriend, football player Mark James, is a bully who torments both John and Sam.
>
> During the Halloween festival Sam mentions that he knows about Mogadorians from a magazine, They Walk Among Us, a revelation that alarms both John and Henri. Mark and his friends organize a nasty surprise during the haunted hayride: Sarah, John and Sam are left stranded in the woods, where Mark plans to beat John up. John uses his "legacies", which are akin to superpowers, to fend off his attackers and rescues Sarah. In the darkness Sarah does not see John use his legacies, and he quietly warns Mark not to talk (or to let his friends talk) about what happened.
>
> Sarah and John's relationship develops. Henri continues training John to use his legacies, now with an increasing sense of urgency. Henri is unsettled, and tells John that it is not safe to stay. He is also concerned as John is late in developing his telekinesis, a power that he will need to fight the Mogadorians. Later, it is revealed that Sam has seen enough to arouse his suspicions, but John allays them by bluffingly 'admitting' to being an alien. He finds out more about the magazine Sam reads by borrowing a copy. Sam speaks of his belief that his father has been abducted by aliens.

He didn't break a football record, but he is revealed when he uses his powers to overpower a football player.