# Novel: Protagonist goes on quests with a woman (not his girlfriend, "PJ"). Refuses to sleep with her

Tags: story-identification, novel

There was a novel I read 8-9 years ago in high school. I don't remember the main characters name, but he had a girlfriend named PJ. The main character went on a quest with another woman who put him through a few tests, the last one being that she stripped down and basically said *"have your way with me"*, but he refused because of his girlfriend.

I believe there were also bits about some glowing crystals in an underwater cavern. This is all I can think of from the novel.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48849/name-of-book-about-teenage-boy-from-the-future

Answer (score 13):

Could this be [*Firestorm*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/419783.Firestorm), part of the "Caretaker" trilogy of books by David Klass?

The main character does quests (something to do with the ocean) and has a girlfriend called P.J.

> His mother is not his mother. His father is not his father. But if
>   Jack hadn't broken the high school rushing record that night, he never
>   would have known and nothing would have changed. He'd just be going
>   out for pizza, playing football, trying yet again to score with his
>   girlfriend, P.J. But he did break the record. He appeared on the news.
>   And now they've found him. Jack plunges into a space-time-bending game
>   of survival with no way out. The rules are shrouded in secrets. But
>   one thing he learns fast: Trust no one. After centuries of abuse, the
>   earth is dying, and it's up to Jack to reverse the decline before the
>   Turning Point, when nothing will ever be the same again. Beaten into
>   shape by a ninja babe and a huge telepathic man's best friend, Jack
>   hurtles across the ocean to save the future from the present and to
>   solve the mystery of his purpose. Exactly who, or what, is Firestorm,
>   and what does it have to do with Jack? And what comes next when
>   everything you have ever known turns out to be wrong?